# In Python, What is the order of operations for the walrus operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, walrus-operator

It would be very useful if someone could give the answer by adding a W into PEMDAS. Thanks.

Comment: This is a question that can be googled faster than asked.

Comment: @DYZ What did you google? Can you send a link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is lower than everything except the comma operator.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/